# Force an order to go to the status complete

Tags: order-status

We are using a custom module that requires the status: "complete" (I can't change the module because it uses ioncube)

We are also using a payment system that doesn't offer the status option: "complete"

So my question is: How can I force an order to go to the status complete?

PS:
This doesn't work:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->loadByIncrementId('12345');
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);
$order->save();
```

Comment: The solution provided here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/244601/15769
It works for me.<br/>
I hope that It'll be useful for anyone that use Magento 1.9.2.4<br/>
Thanks @ctrl-z pls

Answer (score 12):

It's not allowed to manually set the order state to 'complete' and you should be getting this exception when you call `setState` on the order with the 'complete' state:

> The Order State "complete" must not be set manually.

The reason for this is simple: The 'complete' state (and status, since it's the only state with a status of 'complete') is intended to indicate that an order has been completely filled. I.e. it has been placed, invoiced and shipped to the customer.

Once the order has been invoiced and shipped, Magento will set this state on the order automatically.

If your payment system "doesn't allow" the 'complete' status, then I would not trust it, especially with it being ionCube encoded. If, however, it's because it's handling the invoicing outside of Magento, then you'll need to manually generate an "Offline" invoice for the order so that Magento will recognize that it has been paid for.

Don't try to short-change yourself by working around the problem of the orders not hitting the completed state like they normally should. Instead, fix the actual problem by making sure that orders are both invoiced and shipped in Magento so that they will be marked as complete by the system.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  While it does address reasons this shouldn't be done, that's not a catch-all for everything.  I myself have acquired a situation where most of Magento for order processing is skipped and the order needs to be set to the complete status.

Comment: @Navarr actually it does... see the part about manually generating an offline invoice for the order. Do that, and the order will move to complete regardless of the payment processor being used.

Comment: or, you know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8906785/43790

Comment: @Navarr Sure, one could write directly to the db via SQL too, but that doesn't negate it being a protected state per the model implementation. The best answers don't blindly answer to "let's accomplish x" without addressing the underlying matter. Anyhow, this is the last I'll be commenting here regarding this.

Comment: Engin Check light lit on the car's dashboard. I did not know how to fix the issue. I then removed the fuse that switches that little light on. I think my engine is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To change the state:

```
$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

To change the status:

```
$order->addStatusToHistory(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

And then `$order->save();`

You have to change the state using `setData` to avoid the exception telling you that you can't manually call `setState`

Answer (score -3):

Try this.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
$order_id=$order->getData('entity_id');
$order2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id); 
$order2->setData('state', "new");
    $order2->setStatus("pending");
$order2->save();
```

It works for me on my project ..

Comment: Aha, so you've 'restarted' the order and then set it to: new->pending->completed?

Comment: no I loaded the order and then assigned the new status and state to the order.

Comment: This is state/status new/pending, which is no problem. The actual problem is how to set it to 'complete' manually.

Answer (score -3):

```
$oResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); 

$oConnection = $oResource->getConnection('core_write'); 

$sSql = "UPDATE " . ' ' . $oResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order') .
        " SET status = '" . Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE . "', state = '" . Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE . "' WHERE
entity_id = " . $oOrder->getId();

$oConnection->query($sSql);
```

Comment: I would discourage the use of direct SQL execution and rely on the Magento ORM implementation.