# Magento Create Order programmatically with status complete and payment

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, mobile

I am providing web services of Magento to an Android app and wanted to create order with payment information and status completed.

My app will give information of sold product with payment information then I have to create sales orders immediately in Magento with complete status and payment information.

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/28426/
```

I followed this link and various other links but it creates order with status pending and payment is due.

I have to create sales order with complete status and with done payment.

The order shows like:

```
Grand Total     $0.01
**Total Paid    $0.00**
Total Refunded  $0.00
Total Due   $0.01
Subtotal    $0.01 

I need total paid =$0.01;
```

Comment: Refer to this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/force-an-order-to-go-to-the-status-complete

Answer (score 1):

After you place the order you will need to create an invoice for it. Once you create the invoice for the full amount of the order, it will automatically be placed into the completed state.

See the answer I posted here for a bit more detail on how this works: [Force an order to go to the status complete](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/force-an-order-to-go-to-the-status-complete)